# Using .reduce to sum points for each name

Tags: javascript, sum, grouping, reduce

I have an array of objects that goes like this:

```
var array = [{name: "john", points: 20},
           {name: "jack", points: 12},
           {name: "john", points: 10},
           {name: "jack", points: 2},
           {name: "bill", points: 4}]
```

From this array, I would like to generate a new array with the sum of the points per name, typically like this:

```
var newArray = [{name: "john", points:30},
                {name: "jack", points:14},
                {name: "bill", points:4}]
```

I wrote the following function which works well.

```
function filterArray(array){
    var newArray=[]
    for (i in array){
        var index=newArray.map(x=>x.name).indexOf(array[i].name)
        if (index==-1){
            newArray.push(array[i])
        }
        else{
            newArray[index].points+=array[i].points 
        }
    }
    return newArray;
    }
```

However, I would like to use something possibly more elegant like a .reduce() function. Does someone know how it could be done?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: first do it using `for loop`

Comment: try to study first and test what you learn.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I edited my question with what I attempted first with a for loop. It works well. However I'm curious on how the .reduce() function could be used here. Would be grateful if someone has a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping and the function `Object.values` for extracting the values.

```js
let array = [{name: "john", points: 20},{name: "jack", points: 12},{name: "john", points: 10},{name: "jack", points: 2},{name: "bill", points: 4}],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {name, points}) => {
      (a[name] || (a[name] = {name, points: 0})).points += points;
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null)));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```